# Three.js json-imported model dynamically change geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I understand how to change dynamically width, height of standard Geometries from [examples](http://view-source:http://www.smartjava.org/ltjs/chapter-05/04-basic-3d-geometries-cube.html). Could anyone explain how to change imported model geometry via JSONLoader in THREE.js dynamically by dat.gui controls? I found in properties of its model 'faces' and 'vertices' arrays, but I don't understand how to use these arrays for my question.

Comment: Do you want to change an alien into a robot by sliding a slider, or scale a mesh, or something else?

Comment: Change, for instance, imported geometric figure parameters (like height or width) and "rebuild" the one.

Comment: Yes, you need to write something like blender, 3d studio max or maya using three.js